# React - Redux: How to setup Redux with React?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm creating a simple CRUD operation with Redux, but i'm not able to see the action in developer tools which i have created for Redux.

`readAction.js`

```
export const readAction = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: 'READ_USER',
      data: [ { email: 'abc@abc.com'}, { email: 'abc@abc.com'}, { email: 'abc@abc.com'} ]
    })
  }
}
```

`readReducer.js`

```
const initialState = {
  userData: [],
}

export const readReducer = (state = initialState, action = {}) => {
  //console.log(action)
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'READ_USER':
      return {
        ...state,
        userData: action.data
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default readReducer;
```

Developer tool in which i am not able to see the `redux action`
[image]

Please review below whole sandbox working code.

[codesandbox.io/embed/naughty-poincare-7tz02](http://codesandbox.io/embed/naughty-poincare-7tz02)

Comment: you dont seem to be dispatching that action anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look like you didn't config `window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__`. Please check this link for more detail step by step

https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension